# How to modify the JSON data using RapidJSON by modifying it to a different schema

Tags: c++, rapidjson

I have to modify a JSON data to a different schema using RapidJson. I can modify a Value objects name and value but I could not find the right examples so that I can modify the JSON by rearranging the nodes.

I tried by creating a new document and adding the Value taken from the other document but it is not working.

```
    rapidjson::Document doc1, doc2;
            rapidjson::Document::AllocatorType& alloc = doc1.GetAllocator();
            doc1.Parse(str); // str contains the JSON data

            Value statusObj(doc1["status"], alloc);
            Value resultsObj(doc1["area_data"]["update_results"], alloc);

            doc2.SetObject();
            doc2.AddMember("status", statusObj, alloc);
            doc2.AddMember("results", resultsObj, alloc);

//doc1 - This is the inout JSON
{
    "status": {},
    "area_data":
    {
        ""
        "update_results":[]
    }
}

//doc2 - This is what am trying to create
{
    "status": {},
    "results":[]    //update_results from doc 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do it. It works!

```
            rapidjson::Document doc, newDoc;
            rapidjson::Document::AllocatorType& alloc = doc.GetAllocator();
            doc.Parse(str); // str contains the JSON data

            Value& results = doc["area_data"]["update_results"];

            Value newResults(kArrayType);

            newResults.CopyFrom(results, alloc);

            doc.AddMember("results", newResults, alloc);
            doc.RemoveMember("area_data");
```